# How can a mass radiate out more heat than it receives?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to the S-B Law, an area of mass will radiate out heat energy equal to the fourth power of its temperature in degrees Kelvin.

If energy cannot be created nor destroyed, how can a body give off more heat than it receives?

I understand how a magician seems to make a pigeon appear from nowhere, but I can't understand how so much more heat is being radiated out than was absorbed by the mass.  How is this possible?

Comment: TLDR: A body cannot radiate more energy than it receives forever. As it radiates, it's losing its _internal_ energy. It's cooling down. It continues to cool down until it reaches an equilibrium with its environment--a temperature where the power  of its radiation is equal to the power of the radiation it receives.

Comment: That does not answer the question. How can a body radiate heat energy equal to the 4th power of its temperature when the heat energy it has is represented by its temperature? Where dose all that extra 4th power heat energy come from.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Stefan-Boltzmann law the amount of radiation emitted per unit time from area A of a **black body at absolute temperature** T is directly proportional to the fourth power of the temperature. This law describes the behavior of a black body, which is an idealized object that absorbs all incident radiation and emits radiation across all wavelengths.

When an object is radiating heat, it means that it is emitting thermal radiation in the form of electromagnetic waves. This radiation carries energy away from the object, reducing its internal energy and, consequently, its temperature. The energy being radiated by the object is the same energy that was previously absorbed from other sources or generated within the object itself.

In a system where multiple bodies interact, the total energy remains conserved. When one body radiates heat, the emitted radiation can be absorbed by other bodies in the surroundings, thereby transferring energy between them. This transfer of energy through radiation helps maintain the overall energy balance within the system, ensuring that the total energy is conserved.

In summary, the Stefan-Boltzmann law describes the relationship between the temperature and the amount of radiation emitted by a black body. The radiated heat represents energy being transferred from the object, and it is absorbed by other bodies, contributing to the conservation of energy in the system.

Comment: Stephanie constant refers to black bodies it is Sigma times T to the 4th power.  Epsilon times Sigma, time T to the 4th power is the S-B Law.  It applies to all masses not black bodies.  Also, you did not answer the question.  The body warmed to 78f degrees will radiate out an amount of heat equal to 78x78x78x78.  = 37,015,036F degrees of heat!!!!!!!!!! Where is all that heat energy coming from if it's temperature is only 78F degrees to start with?

Answer (score 2):

It does so by getting cooler. A warm object has a lot of energy by virtue of being warm. It can radiate this energy away in the form of electromagnetic radiation, but to do so, its energy must of course decrease, making the object cooler. For this reason, it can't radiate away an arbitrary amount of energy. Once it has cooled down, that energy is gone (to somewhere else in the universe).

As for radiating away more than it receives: After some (possibly long) time passes, the object's temperature will decrease such that it will also radiate away less energy per time. If it is continuously receiving energy from outside sources, it will cool down to the point where it radiates away just as much as it receives. We say that the object is in thermal equilibrium with its surroundings. But before this equilibrium is reached, it can radiate away more than it receives, provided that it already has a high amount of energy, possibly received at some earlier point in time.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  If its starting temperature is only 87F degrees, how can it radiate out more than 87F degrees of heat?  Yet THE S-B Law say it will radiate at the 4th power of its temperature!  How is it possible, where does all that heat come from?  Do the math, 87x87x87x87!  Where is all that heat coming from.  After giving off only 87 degrees it should be out of heat.

Comment: @BudWilliams Several things. First: Temperature is not heat. Heat has units of energy, temperature hasn't. You really can't compare such quantities based on their numerical value at all. Second: What grows with $T^4$ is not radiated heat, but radiated power, that is, heat per time. It is perfectly possible to radiate away $40$ Watts of power while having only $20$ Joules of energy. You just can't keep that up for more than half a second.

Answer (score 1):

Think of standing with your front towards  a camp fire on a cold night.

Your back feels cold and your front feels hot.

You are radiating heat but the radiant heat arriving from the fire on your front is greater as the fire's temperature is greater than you body temperature. and so there is a net inflow of heat to your front.

On the other hand, in terms of temperatures and heat flow, the reverse is true for your back as the temperature of you back is higher than that of the surrounding air.

Putting an object, which does not generate heat, in an environment where the temperature of the object is higher than that its surroundings will result in a net outflow of heat from the object to the surroundings.
The temperature of the object will decrease until its temperature is equal to that of the surroundings at which stage the inflow and outflow of heat to object will be the same.

Comment: Didn't answer the question.  Read it again.

Comment: @BudWilliams I thought I had by saying that a net outflow of energy results in the temperature of the body decreasing?

Answer (score -2):

Energy is converted so at ots basic level a source is emitting to the body.
Sunlight for example turning object hot even on cool day.
Radiation converts as black body from adjacent applied source where it may be concerted into heat.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.